# npx create-react-app my-app not working on mac: stack Error: missing script: start

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am blocked at my first step on learning react framework. 
Appreciate any pointers on getting my unblocked.
Details are below.

```
#####CMD USED: npx create-react-app my-app after installing node and npm on MAC OS Catalina version 10.15.2#####
######DEBUG LOG START#######################################################
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v13.6.0
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:436:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:434:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:350:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:115:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:256:13)
5 verbose cwd /Users/vdeekonda/Desktop/learning/react/my-app
6 verbose Darwin 19.2.0
7 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
8 verbose node v13.6.0
9 verbose npm  v6.13.4
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
######DEBUG LOG END#######################################################
```

Comment: check pacakge.json have "start" in scripts, 
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    ...
  },

Comment: my-app cat package.json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  }
}

I wonder why it does not have start scripts and also wonder what else is missing.

I thought the steps to start are :

1. brew install node
2. brew install npm
3. npx create-react-app my-app

But not working for me ...